# Alternatives to Google Notifier

Tags: gmail, google

Like many people, I’ve received today an email from Google telling me that [Google Notifier Beta is no longer supported](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10960?hl=en) and will stop working on January 31. That is too bad. (BTW, I have 1.10.7, not a Beta version. What are they talking about?)

What are some simple alternatives to Google Notifier?

I’ve looked at Gmail Notifr and at GmailStatus but they are not really the same as Google Notifier. Are there any Google Notifier clones around?

I’m looking for a menu-bar app, not a browser add-on.

EDIT (Mar 10): Google Notifier seems to have stopped working today. That's sad.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. But it seems a simple notifier w/o entering this whole Mail.app business is impossible.

Comment: Google Notifier is still working...

Comment: Is it possible that you can send me a binary file of 1.10.7 version? Thanks.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao, try https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19272/google-notifier/ .

Comment: That's 1.10.4. I wonder if 1.10.7 has notification from only priority mailbox?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao, try http://mac.majorgeeks.com/files/details/google_notifier.html .

Comment: Thanks. That works. :) Still no label function implemented, oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just installed Mail Notifr - $2.99 on AppStore, or free if you download the previous version here: http://ashchan.com/projects/gmail-notifr

At least the paid version looks nice, clean, and in terms of functionality it's pretty similar to Google's Notifier, less Calendar notifications. Mail check frequency can be set in Preferences (Google's was a hidden undocumented feature); multiple GMail accounts are supported. I just hope it's stable and reliable enough. We'll see.

**Update:** so far so good. One little nice thing about this app is that when the system wakes up from sleep it checks for email immediately, whereas with Google Notifier you had to wait another 5 minutes or force mail check manually.

**Update 2**: one other thing missing compared to Google Notifier is handling of mailto: links and in general, redirecting to GMail when trying to send mail from any desktop app. Mail Notifr doesn't do this. Would be nice to have actually.

Comment: It does look good, now that I've tried it again. I went for the free version for now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

One tool is Notify.app which has long been abandoned by the developer but still works flawlessly (OS X 10.9.4):

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32217/notify-pro

And the free pro license upgrade here:

https://anonfiles.com/file/6bdc702e9f055dcc744b7110a620f1f6

Do note, it uses [Growl](http://growl.info/) for the notifications, not the (new) in-built Notification Center in OS X that Apple had added - so you will need to install Growl (which is now a paid app on the Mac App Store and no longer free, though you can probably find older binaries of the formerly free Growl all the same) and then notifications will show.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome, you can try Google Mail Checker (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff). Although it doesn't have notifications pop up when you receive new emails, it will tell you how many unread messages are in your inbox.

Comment: I’m looking for a menu-bar app, not a browser add-on. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail Notifier can be replaced with [Checker Plus for Gmail](http://jasonsavard.com/checkerPlusForGmail) which has desktop notifications and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try [MiaForGmail](https://www.miaforgmail.com/), a desktop email client for your Mac without a browser.

It's simple and it's free.

Comment: I use this too. It's running like Google Notifr with but it will open the email when you click on it. It's lightweight and simple. Good for managing multiple gmail accounts

Comment: unfortunately, this program crashes all the time and is sometimes unresponsive. i've been using mia for about a year now and, overall, it's not very impressive.